# Is it possible to remove elements from PriorityQueue?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

Is it possible to remove elements from PriorityQueue?

Documentation:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator

I have a PQ w various double values (some duplicates) - I use it as a heap to keep track of rolling medians in a streaming environment. I want to remove values from PQ but can't figure out how.
I tried to use the iterator to find an element of the PQ and drop there, but it didn't work. I wonder if it's even possible?

```
val maxHeapLeft= new mutable.PriorityQueue[Double]()(Ordering[Double])
maxHeapLeft.enqueue(5)
maxHeapLeft.enqueue(55)
maxHeapLeft.enqueue(25)
maxHeapLeft.enqueue(15)
maxHeapLeft.enqueue(15)
val it= maxHeapLeft.iterator
var p1=it.next
p1=it.next

println("size before " +maxHeapLeft.size)
it.drop(1)
println("size AFTER " +maxHeapLeft.size)
```

Size of PQ doesn't change.

**EDIT 1:** So far I use `maxHeapLeft= new mutable.PriorityQueue[Double]()(Ordering[Double]) ++ (maxHeapLeft.toList diff List(15))` to remove 15 from the PQ. Of course, terrible.

**EDIT 2:** A test case (for @Nate) that fails for the custom priority queue:

```
 "PQ" should "produce correct values " in {
    val testOperations = List[String]("8114.0", "9233.0", "dequeue", "10176.0", "10136.0", "dequeue", "10041.0", "9900.0", "10787.0", "10476.0", "10439.0", "dequeue", "10722.0", "9900.0", "11028.0", "10764.0", "dequeue", "10698.0", "10374.0", "dequeue", "-10176.0", "10198.0", "-10136.0", "11478.0", "10930.0", "dequeue", "10881.0", "dequeue", "10555.0", "dequeue", "-10787.0", "10439.0", "-10476.0", "11596.0", "-10439.0", "10757.0", "-10722.0", "10493.0", "10551.0", "dequeue", "-11028.0", "10493.0", "-10764.0", "11892.0", "-10698.0", "11276.0", "10917.0", "dequeue", "15855.0", "dequeue", "12008.0", "dequeue")
    val customPQ= new PriorityQueue[Double]()(Ordering[Double].reverse) //cread min heap

    for (el <-testOperations){
      el match {
        case dequeue if el=="dequeue" => customPQ.dequeue()
        case remove if remove.toDouble < 0 => customPQ -= (-1*remove.toDouble )
        case add => customPQ.enqueue(add.toDouble )
      }
    }

    println(customPQ.head + "==" + customPQ.min)
    println(customPQ)
  }
```

**Test output:**
10881.0==10757.0
PriorityQueue(10881.0, 10917.0, 11596.0, 10930.0, 11276.0, 11892.0, 12008.0, 11478.0, 10757.0, 15855.0)

Comment: Iterator's drop method does not remove the element, instead it just moves the iterator forward. Can you please tell how you want to remove an element? If you just want to remove a particular value, you can just use filter. If you want to remove from a particular index, you may be able to use combination of take and drop methods.

Comment: @mohit I have duplicates so a filter would remove all, which is not what I want. I want heap behaviour and the ability to also remove an element by value (and reheapify)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the relevant code to modify PQ on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation you can only remove elements by `clear` and `dequeue`.

Perhaps you'd be happy with a the increased costs of a [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) to obtain the functionality you seek.

If you wanted to remove a specific value that is in the heap, then you could roll your own starting with the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.scala).

**EDIT:**

[Here is an updated version of PriorityQueue](https://gist.github.com/nbauernfeind/4a2bb1d618755f820426) that offers `O(n)` removal. Here is the relevant added code snippet:

```
def -=(elem: A): this.type = {
  var k: Int = find(elem)
  resarr.p_size0 = resarr.p_size0 - 1
  resarr.p_swap(k, resarr.p_size0)
  fixUp(resarr.p_array, k)
  fixDown(resarr.p_array, k, resarr.p_size0 - 1)
  this
}

protected def find(elem: A): Int = {
  var k: Int = 1
  while (k < resarr.length) {
    if (resarr.p_array(k) == elem) {
      return k
    }
    k += 1
  }
  throw new NoSuchElementException("element does not exist in heap")
}
```

I leave adding a `MultiMap` as an exercise to the reader/OP if he/she desires an `O(lg n)` removal. (Hint: you will need to update all methods that modify the `resarr` array.)

**Edit 2:**

Running it locally:

```
$ scalac -version 
Scala compiler version
2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL 

$ md5 PriorityQueue.scala  
MD5 (PriorityQueue.scala) = 3913496441f83bcdeda2249ec2a6b574 

$ scalac PriorityQueue.scala  

$ scala Test 
size before 4 
size after 3
```

Comment: This is useful; compiler can't find class `AbstractIterable[A]`

Comment: Possibly you're running this in a REPL; in this case the class definition needs to be on one line (there might be other newline issues too). Or possibly the import is different for non 2.11 versions of Scala. See my edit 2 to see if that helps you get started.

Comment: I use scala 2.10 and don't use REPL. I pulled the 2.10 version of PQ and tried to compile it just as it is w/o your modifications. I get several errors of the same type but this is just one of them: `Error:(32, 11) class AbstractIterable in package collection cannot be accessed in package collection
  extends AbstractIterable[A]`

Comment: The problem is that `AbstractIterable` is privately scoped to package `scala`. So your `PriorityQueue` needs to start out in package `scala`. Here is a working gist for 2.10: https://gist.github.com/nbauernfeind/f406d79c970a8378dec6

Comment: I thought it might be something like that or missing implicits. Your last comment contains a version that works for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For others who are interested in this: this solution is in fact not working. Took some testing to figure it out, but there are cases when the priorities of the elements get messed up - just wanted to let everyone know. I will still leave this answer as the solution to the question.

Comment: @Adrian Are your elements mutable?

Comment: They're type Double, so no.

Comment: @Adrian Yes I think I may see the issue. The find() method is wrong. Set `var k: Int = 1` instead of 0. And the while loop conditional should be `while (k < resarr.length)`. Also, any chance you have a test that reproduces it in case this didn't work?

Comment: @Adrian Got it! A shorter example is `("1", "4", "2", "5", "6" ,"3", "-5", "7", "dequeue", "dequeue", "dequeue")`. What's happening is that removal of one side is causing a smaller element to be beneath a larger one. The fix is to fixUp and fixDown on removal. I've updated the gist and the answer. Only one of these methods will have any affect and the total cost of removal remains at `O(n + lg(n))`.

Comment: I thought it might be sth like that... tried to do a fixDown myself but was not sure what the correct params are. Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help very much. Do you think it makes sense to add this method to the official PQ?

Answer (score 2):

Revise corectness of using `PriorityQueue` for your task. If you need similar API with unique values use `SortedSet`.

Comment: Sets cannot contains duplicates; I need duplicates. A sorted multiset would be nice.

Comment: FWIW Guava has a SortedMultiset: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can always filter out a single element like so (in non-concurrent code):

```
var filtered = false
pq.filter(x => !filtered && { val ok = p(x); if (!ok) filtered = true; ok })
```

That said, this is rebuilds the entire queue (save one element) every time, which may not be fast enough for you.

Comment: This is effectively O(n) removal, too. Probably a slightly higher constant due to reallocating the underlying array every time the heap is reconstructed.

Comment: @Nate - Indeed.  The advantage is it's easy.  The downside is, well, the downside is that this is a job for `case class Item(value: Double, n: Int = 1)` and `mutable.SortedSet[Item]`.

Comment: Not a perfect solution for a median because the number of entries affect the median. Your solution, a.k.a. a `TreeMap[Double, Int]`, would require `O(n)` time to compute. Better is a `SortedMultiset[Double]` which could be found in `O(lg(n))`.

Comment: @Nate - If you need the median not-so-often, I agree.  Otherwise you may as well keep track of it as you go, which you can do by walking up or down the SortedSet of Item.  A bit clunky, admittedly.

Comment: Oh of course! Didn't think of that; though I agree that would be some ugly Scala =).

Answer (score 0):

can be done with dequeue and enqueue back to the PriorityQueue

```
  def deleteElementFromQueue(heap: mutable.PriorityQueue[Int],
                             toDelete: Int): Unit = {
    var found = false
    val dequeuedArray = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    while (!found) {
      val dequeuedElement = heap.dequeue()
      if (dequeuedElement == toDelete) found = true
      else dequeuedArray.addOne(dequeuedElement)
    }
    dequeuedArray.foreach(e => heap.enqueue(e))
  }
```